# Touch doesn't show highlight, tapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a bunch of buttons that have a tapGestureRecognizer linked to them, and this preforms the appropriate action.

Since I have so many buttons, I do not want to have to manually link them through an IBAction.

Now the problem that I receive, is that it does not show the showsTouchOnHighlight immediately. I do not know how to fix this, here is the code I used:

```
- (void)tapPress:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender.view;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" 
                                                         bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
    infoView *infoViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:resultButton.currentTitle];
    infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:infoViewController 
                       animated:YES 
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Why are you using a tap gesture recognizer instead of just using the button's touchUpInside event?

Comment: because I have 38 buttons, and I can easily create a gesture recognizer, than link all the buttons through interface builder

Comment: Are you creating the gesture recognizer in code?  You can set a button's target and action in code with an `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` message.  [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)

Comment: yes, but the problem is, is that it doesn't show the touchOnHighlight when the user presses the button, only if the user holds it for half a second, then it shows it.

Comment: I understand that it delays the touchOnHighlight effect when you use a tap gesture recognizer.  Does it delay the touchOnHighlight effect if you use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` and *don't* use a gesture recognizer?

Comment: did it, and it works. Thanks a bunch! How do I award you your rep?

Comment: I have created an answer that you can accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using tap gesture recognizers, try using the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method to set the target and action for each of your buttons.  This should save you the labor of connecting each button in your nib.